# I forgot to set CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO=y

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-parameters

I compiled Linus's latest git tree and I forgot to set CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO=y. How can I make the system behave the same way as if I had set that option before booting into it?